# optimizar carga de un select - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

buen dia, tengo un select que carga una gran cantidad de registros pero al montar el select a mi proyecto se vuelve lento por que carga una gran cantidad de registros, como hago para optimizar mi select y que no se vuelva lento?, he intentado mejorar la carga pero no lo he logrado, si alguien me pudiera colaborar se lo agradecería.

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-jerry-3ug31u?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [carrera, setCarrera] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getcountry3 = async () => {
      const req = await fetch(
        "https://witalenco.com.co/apiWittytalent/dyc/titulos/carreras.php"
      );
      const getres3 = await req.json();
      console.log(getres3);
      setCarrera(await getres3);
    };
    getcountry3();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <select name="carrera" className="form-select">
        <option>--Seleccione --</option>
        {carrera.map((getcon3) => (
          <option key={getcon3.id_titulos} value={getcon3.id_titulos}>
            {" "}
            {getcon3.carrera}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacer que en vez del select con todos los datos, implementar primero un autocompletar que, si no da como resultado menos de 100 filas, no muestre el select.

Comment: como seria con mi código ?

Comment: Depende de como te interese hacerlo. Puedes filtrar la busqueda para que te lo filtre el servidor, o pedir todos los datos =ment en el front y filtrarlos allí. Yo soy partidario de hacer trabajar siempre al servidor. 
No puedo poner "como seria en tu codigo" por que solo veo 4 líneas en tu codigo y no se que experiencia de usuario buscas. Si quieres que el usuario tipee las carreras que esta buscando (input form), o solo en base a clicks (botones) que filtren por Àrea de carrera.. etc. Puedes poner que que listen alfabeticamente y solo mostrar las del a letra que elige.. Hay mil formas.